# Android Listview is not providing me right position

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, listadapter

I am implementing an android `ListView` which sometimes has more then 1000 records.

**This is what I am currently doing:**

- I am fetching the records from database.
- I have one button in my `ListView` layout.
- On button click, I am simply showing my database table's primary key which is set to auto increment.

**The problem is:**

Let's say I have 10 rows when I click on button in first row it returns the value of second row. And when I click on second list button it returns the 3rd value. And if I click on last button in the list it returns the correct value.

**Here is my code of listview adapter:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.R;
import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.activity.ProductDetailResult;
import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.other.SharedPreference;
import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.singloton_classes.ProductResultSingloton;



public class ProductResultListAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    Typeface custom_font;
    String mDrawableName;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private List<ProductResultSingloton> result_items;
    int prod_id;

    public ProductResultListAdaptor(Activity activity, List<ProductResultSingloton> result_items) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.result_items = result_items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return result_items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return result_items.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Viewholder holder;
        if (inflater == null) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.products_list, null);
            holder = new Viewholder();

            holder.modal        = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.prod_result_modal);
            holder.type         = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.prod_result_type);
            holder.observation  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.prod_result_obeservation);
            holder.view_detail  = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.show_detail);
            holder.view_detail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity,Integer.toString(prod_id),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }else {

            holder = (Viewholder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        ProductResultSingloton m = result_items.get(position);

        prod_id = m.getRow_id(); //Database id is set to singlton class.
        holder.modal.setText(m.getCODIGO());
        holder.type.setText(m.getTIPO());
        holder.observation.setText(m.getOBSERVACIONES());

        return convertView;
    }

    static  class Viewholder{
        TextView modal;
        TextView type;
        TextView observation;

        Button  view_detail;

    }
}
```

Any suggestions/help are appreciated. I am stuck in middle of my project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `prod_id = position`

Comment: Is it because your index in db strat from 0 and the index of listView start from 1, or reverse?

Comment: I can not assign position to prod_id because my prod_id is not in sequence because i am apply filteration in database so product id could be any one from all 2000 records

Answer (score 0):

Best way is just set the Tag for Button.

```
holder.view_detail.setTag(m.getRow_id());

//and when button is clicked then fetch the ID of the row from button
holder.view_detail.getTag()
```

or

> "prod_id" declared in the ViewHolder class. It wraps properly.

Comment: But i want to know why we need to set the tag instead of direct access?

Comment: @Bilal You should mark this answer as the correct answer since it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: prod_id is global variable and also you are not setting this value to row. So how you able to get the correct value from row or row items. So we should set the value to row, then only we will get the  proper value.